# ¿Se puede rimar una palabra consigo misma?

Tags: poesía, rima

A ver, que imagino que como poder, poder, se podrá, ya lo hizo [Mecano](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecano_(banda)) [alguna que otra vez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_hay_marcha_en_Nueva_York):

> No hay marcha en Nueva York
>   y los jamones son de York.

Lo curioso es que, según el diccionario, una [rima](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WTyprIY) es:

> 1. f. Identidad de sonidos vocálicos y consonánticos, o solo vocálicos, a partir de la última vocal acentuada en dos o más versos.

Pero no dice que la palabra a rimar tenga que ser diferente a una ya usada. ¿Es posible rimar una palabra consigo misma? Y si es así, ¿se exige que al menos la palabra repetida tenga significados diferentes en cada verso?

Comment: Otro ejemplo de Borges está en _El Hacedor_ (1960), de su _Arte poética_: _Mirar el río hecho de tiempo y agua / y recordar que el tiempo es otro río, / saber que nos perdemos como el río / y que los rostros pasan como el agua_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que tradicionalmente se permitía si se trataba de distintas acepciones, pero no estaba demasiado bien visto. En los últimos tiempos sí es más común.

En [*Para un vocabulario de la rima española*](https://books.google.es/books?id=nhzOJeK3wkMC) (Daniel Devoto, 1995), leemos en p. 65-66:

> **Rima consonante pobre**: para DíezE (v.atenuada) el uso de *ama*: *ama*, verbo y nombre rimados, es el paupérrimo extremo a que puede llegar la consonancia y quienes la usan: excluye el empleo —no llega a considerarlo— de *ama*: *ama* verbo y verbo o de *ama*: *ama* sustantivo y sustantivo, es decir, la rima de una palabra consigo misma (sustantivo y verbo, aunque homófonos, son dos palabras diferentes). Baehr no llega a colocar el consonante pobre entre sus odalidades de la *Reim.* V. también *pobre* y *unísona*.

Lamentablemente, las páginas donde aparecen *pobre* y *unísona* no están disponibles en la vista previa de la página.

En [*Contribución a la historia de las teorías métricas en los siglos XVIII y XIX*](https://books.google.es/books?id=M_KWHXoomucC) (José Domínguez Caparrós, 1975) se habla de una obra de Andrés Bello:

> Después hace Bello unas observaciones del tipo de las siguientes: "Una palabra no puede ser consonante de sí misma...", y no agradan, pues, las rimas *menosprecio* / *precio* / *desprecio*. "La consonancia agrada tanto más, cuando menos obvia parece." De ahí que las terminaciones análogas, al ser "en realidad signos idénticos", deben evitarse en las rimas, "porque parece haber en ellas algo de mezquino y pobre, como si hiciésemos rimar una palabra consigo misma. Será, pues, más grata, o como suele decirse, más *rica*, la consonante de *sentía* con *dia* que con *temía*...". (...)

De hecho luego encontré este libro: [*Principios de la ortolojía y métrica de la lengua castellana*](https://books.google.es/books?id=yxlHAQAAMAAJ) (Andŕes Bello, 1844) y la referencia aparece en la página 94.

Luego en la página 332 de [*Diccionario Akal de Términos Literarios*](https://books.google.es/books?id=FmHTX6p1qo4C) se dice:

> La perceptiva tradicional no permitía que una palabra rimase consigo misma, pero la poesía del siglo XX recurre con frecuencia a la autorrima, por ejemplo:
>
> La fuente aleja su cantata.
>   Despiertan todos los caminos...
>   ¡Mar de la aurora, mar de plata;
>   qué limpio estás entre los pinos!
>   Viento del sur, ¿vienes sonoro
>   de soles? Ciegan los caminos...
>   ¡Mar de la siesta, mar de oro;
>   qué alegre estás sobre los pinos!
>   Dice el verdón no sé qué cosa...
>   Mi alma se va por los caminos...
>   ¡Mar de la tarde, mar de rosa;
>   qué dulce estás entre los pinos!
>
> (Juan R. Jiménez: "El mar lejano")

Comment: Buena respuesta, y palabra nueva que he aprendido: _ortología_ ("rama de la fonética que establece las normas convencionales de pronunciación de una lengua").

Comment: El ejemplo de Juan Ramón me parece un poco traído por los pelos, pues es una autorrima reiterada en un poema basado en la reiteración. Es decir: una autorrima justificada por el contexto.

Comment: Investigando el tema de _autorrima_, _rima unisonante_...

Answer (score 5):

Hay que tener en cuenta que la rima es un recurso eminentemente vocal.  La usaban los trovadores para hacer más atractivas las historias, glosas y canciones que transmitían a sus oyentes, mucho mucho mucho antes de que ninguno de ellos supiera escribir o leer siquiera (y por supuesto, mucho antes de que existiese un órgano regulador de la lengua).
Por eso, en poesía no tiene sentido aplicar reglas basadas en la escritura: la [rima](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rima), la [sinalefa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinalefa), incluso la [métrica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9trica) misma de los versos se basan todas en cómo se *oye* lo que se está leyendo, no en como se ve.
Así, si el autor te dice que "estas dos palabras hay que pronunciarlas separadas, aunque la una acabe y la otra empiece por vocal", entonces no hay sinalefa que valga, por mucho que debiera haberla según la escritura.

En base a lo anterior, en principio sí se puede rimar una palabra consigo misma. Por definición, de hecho. Pero es una rima muy pobre y demuestra falta de creatividad :) Aunque podrías escaquearte argumentando que estás usando una [figura estilística de repetición](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figura_literaria#Figuras_de_repetici.C3.B3n).

No obstante, aunque no haya cuerpo regulador ni reglas "oficiales", la mayoría de estudiosos del tema (ver por ejemplo [aquí](https://books.google.es/books?id=nhzOJeK3wkMC&lpg=PA107&ots=Y9NGeJqMf3&dq=rimar%20misma%20palabra&hl=es&pg=PA107#v=onepage&q=%22por%20regla%20general%20no%20debe%20rimar%20la%20misma%20palabra%22&f=false)) coinciden en que no es lícito usar este tipo de rima en poesía.
Salvo que seas [Pablo Neruda](http://www.neruda.uchile.cl/obra/obra20poemas3.html):

> *Como todas las cosas están llenas de mi **alma**,
>
>   emerges de las cosas, llena del alma mía.
>
>   Mariposa de sueño, te pareces a mi **alma**,
>
>   y te pareces a la palabra melancolía.*
>
> (Pablo Neruda)