# ¿Qué significado tiene "guantes" en esta canción de Silvio Rodríguez?

Tags: vocabulario, letras-de-canciones, poesía, cuba

La canción "[La leyenda de los Amantes](https://www.letras.com/silvio-rodriguez/1706294/)" de Silvio termina así:

> Y se hicieron leyenda los dos amantes
>   Enroscados eterna y húmedamente
>   Nada pudo tocarlos **detrás de guantes**
>   Solo pueden saberlo los igualmente.

Ninguna acepción de [*guantes*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=guante) parece tener sentido. ¿Alguien sabe qué significa eso? ¿Cómo se hila con *los igualmente*?

Comment: Para mi lo extraño de esa estrofa es  "los igualmente". ¿Qué significa eso?

Comment: Debido a esta pregunta, he desayunado esta mañana a ritmo de "ójala" de Silvio (llevaba con ella metida en la cabeza desde que leí la pregunta...). Ese sería otro ejemplo de letras de canciones que son más simbólicas que otra cosa, si es que acaso no responden simplemente a la necesidad de la rima.

Answer (score 6):

Pueden darse bastante varias situaciones distintas en un caso como este.

Quizá se esté usando una de las muchas acepciones de "guante" (y nosotros no entendemos el uso), puede que se use el concepto de "guante" en un sentido metafórico (como algo que te envuelve y protege, entre otras muchas) y sea el lector quien deba interpretarlo, puede que el autor use un sinsentido solo por poder usar la palabra que rime<sup>1</sup>, o puede ser que el uso metafórico esté exagerado hasta alcanzar cotas de estilos como el surrealismo.

Por ejemplo, la obra *Poeta en Nueva York* de Federico García Lorca es *surrealista*, no por ello descuidando la métrica poética.

> Su visión de Nueva York es de pesadilla y desolación, propia de un mal sueño. Para expresar la angustia y el ansia de comunicación que lo embargan, emplea las imágenes visionarias del lenguaje **surrealista**. *Su libertad expresiva es máxima, aunque junto al verso libre se advierte el uso del verso medido* (octosílabo, endecasílabo y alejandrino).
>
> Wikipedia sobre la [obra de Lorca en su juventud](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federico_Garc%C3%ADa_Lorca#.C3.89poca_de_juventud)

El cantautor (y poeta, novelista,...) Leonard Cohen versionó el *[Pequeño vals vienés](https://youtu.be/NsOTXoLLHWY)*, recogido en *Poeta en Nueva York*. La letra de esta canción/poema cae en ese estilo surrealista, futurista y simbólico en el que hay tanto sentido literal como metafórico.

> Te quiero, te quiero, te quiero,
>
> con la butaca y el libro muerto,
>
> por el melancólico pasillo,
>
> en el oscuro desván del lirio,
>
> en nuestra cama de la luna
>
> y en la danza que sueña la tortuga.
>
> ¡Ay, ay, ay, ay!
>
> Toma este vals de quebrada cintura.
>
> Fragmento de [Pequeño Vals Vienés de Lorca](https://www.poemas-del-alma.com/pequeno-vals-vienes.htm)

Compara por ejemplo con

> mis manos que aún son de hueso
>
> y tu vientre sabe a pan
>
> la catedral es tu cuerpo...
>
> eras verano y mil tormentas, yo
>
> el león que sonríe a las paredes
>
> que he vuelto a pintar del
>
> mismo color
>
> [Héroes del Silencio: La Chispa Adecuada](https://youtu.be/jnDjEHyhFpU?t=1m14s)

Y mencione este par de ejemplos en particular porque aún recuerdo discusiones en clase de lengua (En EGB, ha llovido mucho desde entonces...) en el que discutíamos con el profesor por qué si lo de Lorca era "poesía surrealista" lo de Héroes era un simple sinsentido.

Resumiendo, viendo que ninguna de las acepciones de *guante* se adapta bien, y considerando que Silvio en un cantautor y poeta reconocido, yo asumiría que el sentido es menos literal y más metafórico, llegando a lo surrealista tal vez. Yo asumiría que quiera simbolizar algo que envuelve y protege a estos dos amantes y que solo entienden aquellos que sienten lo que ellos.

---

<sup>1. [¿Se puede rimar una palabra consigo misma?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21100/5481): Autorrima oa rima pobre, por ejemplo.</sup>

Comment: +2 Por citar [Héroes del silencio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnDjEHyhFpU)...No me deja... ok +1 solamente :-)