# ¿Hay palabras en español que no rimen con ninguna otra?

Tags: rima

Soy francés, y en mi idioma tenemos algunos ejemplos de palabras que no riman con nada: *belge*, *quatorze*, *quinze*, *triomphe*... A veces estas palabras tienen [rimas pobres](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21102/13628), pero nunca más.

Estuve preguntándome si lo mismo existe en español. Busqué un poco pero no encontré ejemplos. ¿No hay?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sin rima **consonante** sí  que hay:

En [este blog](http://espejo-ludico.blogspot.com.es/2007/08/palabras-sin-rima.html) se mencionan varías palabras, pero este [buscador de rimas](http://buscapalabras.com.ar/rimas.php) encuentra rimas para varias de ellas, por lo que solo quedarían **dúctil**, **pubis**, **página** y **lágrima**.

Según el artículo de José Domínguez Caparrós [*Palabras sin rima o disonantes*](http://revistas.uned.es/index.php/rhythmica/article/download/13079/12059), ya en 1606 Juan Díaz Rengifo en su *Arte poética española* compiló una lista de palabras, que posteriormente fue ampliada por otros autores. En el artículo se mencionan, entre otras, **cáliz**, **salvia**, **cárcel** y **mármol**.

Edición:
En un comentario @VeAqui señala **coccix**, **fórceps**, además de extranjerismos como **álbum, yang, cómic o molotov** y, realizando una búsqueda con el DLE por terminación como señala @blonfu en su comentario, se pueden encontrar muchas más: **cérvix**, **ónix**, **fénix**, **tribu**, **espíritu**, **ímpetu** ... pero tampoco es cuestión de hacer una lista exhaustiva, sino de poner algunos ejemplos que muestren que, efectivamente, en español hay palabras que no tienen rima consonante.

Comment: Algunas de la primera lista que has puesto si tienen rima, he encontrado para cutis, fútil y púgil buscando en el DRAE por terminación.

Comment: @blonfu: Modificado según hallazgos de un buscador de rimas

Comment: Un fan de Harry Potter hispanoamericano te diría que _cárcel_ rima con _[pársel](http://es.harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/P%C3%A1rsel)_.

Comment: y un maquinista *salvia* con [Alvia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvia)

Comment: y Chiquito de la Calzada (d.e.p.) encontraría rimas para todas...

Comment: con un poco de ayuda del dpd y del sitio de rimas, pueden agregarse cóccix (debido a la x final, pues la forma coxis con s presenta rima consonante) y fórceps, como palabras del *español*. Vocablos como álbum, yang, cómic o molotov entre otros ya entran como *extranjerismos* (unos más cómunes que otros)  (complemento del comentario previo)

Answer (score 9):

En español se contemplan dos tipos de rima:

- **consonante**: cuando coinciden todos los **sonidos**, tanto vocales como consonantes, a partir de la última vocal acentuada.

  - Son rimas consonantes: *espaci**al*** - *let**al***; *podr**ido*** -
    *her**ido***; *extranj**ero*** - *c**ero***; *s**úbito*** - *dec**úbito***; *b**áculo*** - *recept**áculo***.
  - También son rimas consonantes, para un hablante que pronuncie las "c" y "z" como "s" (la inmensa mayoría): *cen**izo*** - *p**iso***, *m**orse*** - *cat**orce***.
- **asonante**: cuando coinciden solamente los **sonidos** de las vocales, desde la última acentuada.

  - Son rimas asonantes: *espaci**a**l* - *alacr**á**n*; *podr**i**d**o*** -  *mol**i**n**o***; *extranj**e**r**o*** - *p**e**ch**o***; *s**ú**b**i**t**o*** -
    ***ú***lt**i**m**o**; *b**á**c**u**l**o*** - *r**au**d**o***.

Además hay que tener en cuenta algunos otros factores:

- Solo hay 5 vocales en español.
- Las rimas no necesitan tener en cuenta más de 3 sílabas*.

El número de combinaciones de vocales que se pueden hacer en 3 sílabas es relativamente limitado. Sin embargo, el número de palabras en español es muy alto, cientos de miles.
Forzosamente habrá varias palabras que compartan la misma combinación de vocales, por inusual que esta sea.

<sub>*Incluso para las palabras sobresdrújulas, como son los adverbios en *-mente* y las formas verbales con sufijos pronominales tipo *-selo*, *-mela* etc., la rima en realidad se busca contra la palabra llana/esdrújula que forma el adverbio o verbo, ya que los sufijos son comunes.</sub>

Por todo lo anterior, **es básicamente imposible que exista en español una palabra que no rime con ninguna otra**. Siempre va a existir rima asonante al menos.

Ahora bien, si limitamos la pregunta a las rimas consonantes (que es a lo que se refiere la mayoría de gente cuando dice que dos palabras "riman"), entonces sí, existen algunas palabras que no tienen rima consonante con ninguna otra y que ya han sido mencionadas en otras respuestas, como [la de Cyanide](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23297/13628).

Comment: En cierto acento, cierto parque urbano, el Paseo Bravo, se pronuncia como "Paseo Brap".  ¿Hay algo que rime con *Brap*?  Yo no encuentro nada.  (Pero yo no tengo talento para encontrar las rimas.)

Comment: @aparente001 eso es un poco raro ya que no es lo normal ese tipo de pronunciación en español pero acabado en **ap** podríamos usar los extranjerismos totalmente integrados *rap* o *hándicap*

Comment: @walen - Ahora entiendo, gracias.