# What rhymes with feliz?

Tags: poesía, música, rima

I have a line in a song that is
"Pero el mundo es grande y feliz,"

But I need a last line that ends with a word that rhymes with "feliz". Line might begin with "Pero" or "Y".

I guess I better give whole context:

> Ellos digan mal de ti,
> Y Ellos digan mal de mi,
> Pero el mundo es grande y feliz,
> Y...

I have [tons of words offered](https://rimar.io/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=feliz&adv_rhy=Rimas&typeofrhyme=adv&lang=es&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y) in the Spanish Rhyming Dictionary but my Spanish is limited.

Maybe this is not the place to post this, but maybe it could start a dialogue. Gracias.

Comment: Do you want a word that rhymes with "feliz"? Or do you want us to suggest you a whole verse that rhymes with the previous one? You seem to have lots of words that rhyme with "feliz" so I'm confused. Please clarify the question _y así seré feliz cual perdiz_. :-)

Comment: I guess this could be something for the chat ["la tertulia"](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) but not for the site

Comment: Alguna palabra habrá, ya que "feliz" no está entre las palabras sin rima que descubrimos en [¿Hay palabras en español que no rimen con ninguna otra?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23296/5481). Yo, por cierto, estoy _feliz como una lombriz_ de ayudar, pero creo que esta pregunta debería cerrarse (que queda claro lo que pide y creo que puede haber múltiples respuestas igualmente válidas, como una pregunta cuya respuesta es "opinion based" )

Comment: Definitely I think this is more suitable for out chat room. A valid question would be "what rhymes with 'feliz'" or even "what are the most common words that rhyme with 'feliz'", but you are asking us to compose a whole verse for you so this question is mostly opinion-based. You are invited then to _[La tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia)_ to ask this same question there and we'll gladly try to help you.

Comment: Jejeje! Thank you and I will review my options. I don't need a whole verse, just trying to show that I am not crazy. Now I know about chat, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RAE's DLE allows you to search by the starting or ending characters of a word. As such (and given that in distinción dialects word terminal "-iz" only rhymes with "-iz"), you can search whether you want to rhyme only the final syllable ["-iz"](https://dle.rae.es/iz?m=32):

- *actriz, cicatriz, desliz* etc

or the final two ["-eliz"](https://dle.rae.es/eliz?m=32):

- *infeliz, jeliz, veliz*

You can expand this search to include words ending ["-ís"](https://dle.rae.es/%C3%ADs?m=32) or ["-elís"](https://dle.rae.es/el%C3%ADs?m=32) for seseo dialects.

Comment: Thanks brazofuerte!

Comment: Booya! "Infeliz"!!! no se preocupe con los que son infeliz. I will have to "throw" the phrase but it is perfect. Gold star to brazofuerte! Abrazo fuerte!  El mundo es grande y feliz, No se preocupe con los que son infeliz. I love this stackexchange group.

Comment: My Costa Rica friend who I was writing the song with reminds me that the plural of "feliz" is "felices".